# The best way to implement a remote desktop viewer

Tags: vb.net, performance, remote-desktop

I am an experienced vb.net programmer and have completed many projects, however I want to be able to view the desktop in almost-realtime from a computer on my lan (its part of my business)

As this is a business situation teamviewer is not free, but id rather like to make my own server and client anyway - will be fun! :)

I need to know the best way of sending the desktop fast to the second computer. I know of several ways to do this:

1. take image of screen be it jpeg/bmp or whatever and send it as many times a second as i can (too slow)
2. take an image of the screen and compare it with the previous image and send the bytes that have changed...
3. take multiple images of the screen compare with previous images and send thorugh the bytes that have changed...

RDP is obviously really advanced, but I dont want to connect to it - I would like to build my own programs.

Can anyone offer advice?

Thanks in advance, Dave.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use RDP or VNC and spend your time on something which will give your business a competitive edge.

However there are several open source VNC implementations. I believe they use hexagons to detect changes. Anyway if you google VNC you will drop in on these projects.